# Sending POST response from a Variable using Express.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to list files sending a `POST` request, but I can't figure out what's wrong with what I am doing. Here's my function:

```
app.post('/api/list', function(req,res){
   listFiles();
   res.send(files);
});
```

And here is my `listFiles` function and test variable :

```
var files = "";
var listFiles = function(){
   fs.readdir(testFolder, (err, files) => {
      files.forEach(file => {
      files += file;
   });
   console.log(files);
  })
};
```

I can see the paths with a `console.log` output. But, when I use `res.send(files);` in the `POST`, the files aren't shown - it's empty. Here's what I've written in jQuery to show the files:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
  var item = $(this).text().replace(/ /g, "-");
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/api/list',
    success: function(data){
      //do something with the data via front-end framework

      alert('response : ' + data);
      //location.reload();
    }
  });
});
```

My connection is okay if I send `res.send("test");`. I can make that alert message as `"response : test"`. But when I try to send a variable it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to async programming! :)

`fs.readdir` works asynchronously, so when you call `listFiles()`, that returns immediately and goes on to the next line - `res.send(files)`. At that moment `files` really still is an empty string, so that's what you're seeing.

The callback of `fs.readdir` is actually executed **after** `res.send(files)` finishes, so you would either need to execute `res.send()` in the same `fs.readdir` callback, or control the flow with Promises.

Here are a few examples:

1. Pass `res` to listFiles, execute `res.send()` after you have the output you need

   `var listFiles = function (res) {
       fs.readdir(..., (err, files) => {
           var filesString = "";
           files.forEach(...)
           res.send(filesString)
       })
   };

   app.post('/api/list', function(req,res){
      listFiles(res);
   });`
2. Pass a callback to listFiles, similar to the first one but following the same pattern `fs.readdir` uses

   `var listFiles = function (callback) {
       fs.readdir(..., (err, files) => {
           var filesString = "";
           files.forEach(...)
           callback(filesString)
       })
   };

   app.post('/api/list', function(req,res){
      listFiles((filesString) => res.send(filesString));
   });`
3. Wrap `fs.readdir` in a Promise (you can also use `util.promisify` for this, check out the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original))

   `var listFiles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         fs.readdir(..., (err, files) => {
           var filesString = "";
           files.forEach(...)
           return resolve(filesString)
       })
   })

   app.post('/api/list', function(req,res){
      listFiles().then((filesString) => res.send(filesString))
      // or, even better as Express can reply with a Promise directly
      // res.send(listFiles())
   });`

There's a nice series about NodeJS, async programming and the event loop, I recommend you to read up on it so you get the hang of the bigger picture: https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810. Also, check out the stuff related to **[async/await](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/)**, it makes Promises that much nicer to work with in most cases.

Comment: I'm actually new to javascript :) Thank you soo much this detailed explanation. I will definitely check this link too. I tried first example and it's working really good. I will try second too it will be good example for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I am glad to help! This is actually one of the biggest hurdles to overcome when coming from more traditional or introductory languages such as C, Python or PHP where async stuff is either nonexistent or not paid any attention to in classes/tutorials, so as soon as you wrap your head around the async stuff and some of the inner workings of Node (eg. the event loop), everything will be much easier to reason about. Best of luck!